# My language-region translation files are not recognized under the right directories (values-pt-rPT and values-pt-rBR)

Tags: android, localization, region

I have a localized app. for the translation I have many strings.xml files under different directories (under /res folder).
two of them are values-pt-rPT and values-pt-rBR to support Portuguese-Portugal and Portuguese-Brazil.

when I run the app, I see english instead of Portuguese. after some tests it seems that these directories are ignores, although they are defined as in the documentation.
I tried creating a values-pt, to test, and then Portuguese appeared in the app, but when the region is added to the directory, nothing is detected and it falls back to English.

note: tested on Pixel, Android 9.0

Can anyone help?

I tried using only values-pt directory which helped to display Portuguese but not region-specific.
I tried it also with French-Canada and French-France, and the same problem occurred. it seems that the problem is that Android doesn't detect the region-specific directories.

[resource files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehep4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer myself.
it seems that I had to add the 2 region languages files to my build.gradle file under defaultConfig { }

```
 defaultConfig {
    ..
    resConfigs "pt-rPT" ,"pt-rBR" // just the addition here
}
```

that fixed my problem.